# Improving matrix multiplication in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, matrix-multiplication

me and some friends are doing a small language competition to calculate some neural networks. Some doing in C other in fortran, and me: Python.

The code is simple, is just a bunch of vector dot operations and a summation after that apply a signal function and return -1 or 1 (activated or not).

With that we are sending a bunch of random numbers and checking (right now only single process) which language do it faster.

My code is simple as this:

```
def sgn(h):
    """Signal function"""
    return -1 if h < 0 else 1

def lincomb(A, B):
    """Linear combinator between two matrices"""
    return np.einsum('ji,ij->', A, B)

def lincombrav(A, B):
return A.ravel().dot(B.ravel('F'))

def functional_test():
    w1 = np.random.random(50**2).reshape(50,50)
    w2 = np.random.random(50**2).reshape(50,50)
    return sgn(lincombrav(w1, w2))
```

Where A and B are matrices that represent each layer in a neural network. then we  dot the  ith-column of the first matrix with the ith-row for the second matrix, sum all results and send to signal function. Something like:

```
w1 = 2*np.random.random(100**2).reshape(100,100)-1
w2 = 2*np.random.random(100**2).reshape(100,100)-1
```

then we time it with

```
%timeit sgn(lincomb(w1, w2))
```

Python is losing to Fortran by 38x :-(

Is there anyway to improve that Python "code".

EDIT: Added timeit results:

Python version (already with the `ravel` mode)

```
In [10]: %timeit functional_test()
8.72 µs ± 406 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Python version (with `einsum`)

```
In [16]: %timeit functional_test()
10.27 µs ± 490 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Fortran version

```
In [13]: %timeit fort.test()
235 ns ± 12.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Fortran version was created using "f2py" program, to generate a python loadable module from fortran code.

The test functions do the following (in each language):

1. Create the matrix A
2. Create the matrix B
3. call sgn(lincomb(A,B))  # from each respective language implementation

I also moved the matrix creation to outside, to run only the mathematical operation instead also handling memory. Still, python is behind by same magnitude.

EDIT2: Good python news. Python has won in all but the small matrix tests. Here will follow the whole code:

### Python functions (bla.py)

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sgn(h):
    """Signal function"""
    return -1 if h < 0 else 1

def lincomb(A, B):
    """Linear combinator between two matrices"""
    return np.einsum('ji,ij->', A, B)

def lincombrav(A, B):
    return A.ravel().dot(B.ravel('F'))

def functional_test_ravel(n):
    """Functional tests (Victor experiment)"""

    w = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1
    x = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1

    return sgn(lincombrav(w, x))

def functional_test_einsum(n):
    """Functional tests (Victor experiment)"""

    w = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1
    x = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1

    return  sgn(lincomb(w, x))

@jit()
def functional_test_numbaein(n):
    """Functional tests (Victor experiment)"""

    w = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1
    x = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1

    return sgn(lincomb(w, x))


@jit()
def functional_test_numbarav(n):
    """Functional tests (Victor experiment)"""

    w = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1
    x = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1

    return sgn(lincombrav(w, x))
```

### Fortran functions (fbla.f95)

```
module fbla
    implicit none
    integer, parameter::dp = selected_real_kind(12,100)
    public

contains

    real(kind=dp) function sgn(x)
        integer, parameter::dp = selected_real_kind(12,100)
        real(kind=dp), intent(in):: x

        if(x >= 0.0 ) then
            sgn = +1.0   
        else if (x < 0.0) then
            sgn = -1.0 
        end if
    end function sgn

    real(kind=dp) function lincomb(A, B, n)
        integer, parameter :: sp = selected_int_kind(r=8)
        integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(12,100)

        integer(kind=sp) :: i
        integer(kind=sp), intent(in):: n
        real(kind=DP), intent(in) :: A(n,n)
        real(kind=DP), intent(in) :: B(n,n)

        lincomb = 0
        do i=1,n
            lincomb = lincomb + dot_product(A(:,i),B(i,:))
        end do
    end function lincomb

    real(kind=dp) function functional_test(n)
        integer, parameter::dp = selected_real_kind(12,100)
        integer, parameter::sp = selected_int_kind(r=8)

        integer(kind=sp), intent(in):: n
        integer(kind=sp):: i, j
        real(kind=dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:):: x, w, wt   

        ALLOCATE(wt(n,n),w(n,n),x(n,n))

        do i=1,n
            do j=1,n
                w(i,j) = 2*rand(0)-1
                x(i,j) = 2*rand(0)-1
            end do
        end do

        wt = transpose(w)
        functional_test = sgn(lincomb(wt, x, n))
    end function functional_test

end module fbla
```

### Test execution functions (tests.py)

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bla
from fbla import fbla

def run_test(test_functions, N, runs=1000):
    results = []
    global rank
    for n in N:
        rank = n
        for t in test_functions:
            # print(f'Rank {globals()["rank"]}')
            print(f'Running {t} to matrix size {rank}', end='')
            r = min(timeit.Timer(t , globals=globals()).repeat(repeat=5, number=runs))
            print(f' total time {r} per run {r/runs}')
            results.append((t, n, r, r/runs))

    return results


def plotbars(results, test_functions, N):
    Nsz = len(N)
    M = len(test_functions)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ind = np.arange(int(Nsz))
    width = 1/(M+1)

    p = []
    for n in range(M):
        g = [ w*1000 for (x,y,z,w) in results if x==test_functions[n]]
        p.append(ax.bar(ind+n*width, g, width, bottom=0))

    ax.legend([ l[0] for l in p ], test_functions)
    ax.set_xticks(ind-width/2+((M/2) * width))
    ax.set_xticklabels(np.array(N).astype(str))
    ax.set_xlabel('Rank of square random matrix')
    ax.set_ylabel('Average time(ms) per run')
    ax.set_yscale('log')

    return fig

N = (10, 50, 100, 1000)
test_functions = [ 
        'bla.functional_test_einsum(rank)', 
        'fbla.functional_test(rank)'
]

results = run_test(test_functions, N)
plot = plotbars(results, test_functions, N)
plot.show()
```

The results are:

```
[('bla.functional_test_einsum(rank)', 10, 0.023221354000270367, 2.3221354000270368e-05),
 ('fbla.functional_test(rank)', 10, 0.005375514010665938, 5.375514010665938e-06),
 ('bla.functional_test_einsum(rank)', 50, 0.07035048000398092, 7.035048000398091e-05),
 ('fbla.functional_test(rank)', 50, 0.1242617039824836, 0.0001242617039824836),
 ('bla.functional_test_einsum(rank)', 100, 0.22694124400732107, 0.00022694124400732108),
 ('fbla.functional_test(rank)', 100, 0.5518505079962779, 0.0005518505079962779),
 ('bla.functional_test_einsum(rank)', 1000, 37.88827919398318, 0.03788827919398318),
 ('fbla.functional_test(rank)', 1000, 74.09929457501858, 0.07409929457501857)]
```

Some standard `timeit` output from a `ipython3` session. `fbla` is the fortran library while `bla` is standard python library.

```
In : n=1000
In : w1 = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1
In : w2 = 2*np.random.random(n**2).reshape(n,n)-1

In : bla.sgn(bla.lincomb(w1,w2))
Out: -1

In : fbla.sgn(fbla.lincomb(w1,w2))
Out: -1.0

In : %timeit fbla.sgn(fbla.lincomb(w1,w2))
11.3 ms ± 430 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In : %timeit bla.sgn(bla.lincomb(w1,w2))
3.81 ms ± 573 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

[image: Python wins]

Comment: I am curious to know if you compiled your Fortran routines with optimization enabled, and if so, which Fortran compiler you used. Also, note that Fortran's intrinsic `dot_product` can be (and in my experience has often been) slower than its do-loop version, although in practical applications the difference might not be worth switching to the uglier do-loop version. Also, some (but not all) of your do-loops can take advantage of Fortran's intrinsic `do concurrent` construct, which in some cases, with compiler optimization flags enabled, can lead to a significant performance gain.

Comment: I changed to a native for loop, it was improved but didn't get better than python. I used `gfortran` with `-O3`, as I did used numpy compiled with gcc (not icc), if you have any other optimizations to send to gfortrans please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can improve a bit with `matrix-multiplication` -

```
sgn(w1.ravel().dot(w2.ravel('F')))
```

Comment: this shaved off just a little. Changed from 38x to 33x, but is an improvement :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you want Numpy to be faster get a faster Numpy. Try uninstalling Numpy and installing the Intel optimized version of Numpy. Intel's optimized version of Numpy includes a number of CPU level optimizations that should significantly improve the performance of operations such as matrix multiplication on machines that use an Intel CPU.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install intel-numpy
```

Comment: install intel numpy (yes I have a intel core i7), makes all my code segfault ;-). Including `f2py3`/`f2py`. I will check why